# Can the mob function in partykit build model trees using regularized linear models, such as ridge regression?

Tags: r-package, party

Is it possible to correctly use regularized linear or generalized linear models with the **mob** function in partykit?

I imagine the null hypothesis of the parameter stability tests that partykit uses would need to change to a non-standard Brownian Bridge because the score function is no longer 0 on the full set of data points, but rather shifted by the gradient of the penalizing term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. However, I've never worked through this in detail and what really would need to be modified to obtain a clean functional central limit theorem.

One ad hoc modification would be to simply substract the mean score from the individual score contributions so that these sum to zero again. My gut feeling is that this should make the resulting test slightly more conservative so that at least you are on the "right side".

Another solution would be to use the conditional inference procedures from `ctree()` rather than the parametric stability tests from `mob()`. You can simply supply the `estfun(model(...))` as the `ytrafo`. Feel free to get in touch with us (Torsten, Heidi, and me) by direct e-mail for more guidance and discussion.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll reach out directly if I have more questions. I'll consider the ctree approach, but I find the idea of controlling model complexity through built-in stability tests simply too elegant to abandon.

Comment: This wasn't clear to us 15 years ago but it turns out that the parameter instability tests in MOB and the conditional inference in CTree are very similar when combined with the same score function. See https://eeecon.uibk.ac.at/~zeileis/news/power_partitioning/

Comment: Also if the answer was helpful to you, please accept it here on StackOverflow so that it is marked as resolved. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't realize that the accept icon was different from the upvote lol. I tried upvoting but didn't have enough reputation. Thank you.